# Using Selenium, enable "Pop-ups and redirects" in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to enable "Pop-ups and redirects" in Chrome using Selenium?
Am I using the '`disable-popup-blocking`' argument incorrectly?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
capabilities = {'chromeOptions':{'useAutomationExtension':False}}
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'
```

When I start Chrome using code above, the setting is still on.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using incorrect setting, at least I fail to see anything like `--disable-popup-blocking` at [Capabilities & ChromeOptions](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) page.

My expectation is that you should amend your code to look like:

```
chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
capabilities = {'chromeOptions':{'useAutomationExtension':False}}
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'
```

More information:

- [Selenium disable popup blocker in different browsers](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-disable-popup-blocker-different-browsers/)
- [Enable Popups](https://docs.experitest.com/display/LT/Enable+Popups)
- [Customizing Chrome with ChromeOptions](https://support.saucelabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002325914-Customizing-Chrome-with-ChromeOptions)

Comment: I tried it. But once the Chrome opens and loads page, I check settings, and the blocker is still on:
`chrome_options = Options()

prefs = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 1}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)   

browser = webdriver.Chrome("G:\\z-BPA\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.google.com")`

Comment: Sorry I should mentioned that. I tried both. It's always set to "Blocked" regardless if it's 0 or 1